# Auto-populating a Google Docs table from a Google Sheet, based on info in the table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a Google Doc that I need to repeatedly fill with info, and I want to make it faster. It is full of info about computers. I want to make it so I can put in my company's asset tag # in the first column, and the script will go to my Google Sheet and grab the serial # and the make and model corresponding to that asset tag, and autofill the other 3 columns of the Google Doc table.

Here's my current script for finding the info of an asset tag.

```
function searchColumn(searchTag) {
    var sourceSheet, targetValues;
    sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("salesforce_data");

    var column = 27; // asset tag column index

    targetValues = sourceSheet.getRange(2, column, sourceSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    //Logger.log(targetValues);

    var matchRow = [];
    const rows = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    //Logger.log(rows);

    targetValues.forEach(function(value, index) {
      //Logger.log(value);
      if (value[0] === searchTag) {
        matchRow = rows[index+1];
      }
    });

    let info = []; // asset, serial, manufacturer, model
    info[0] = matchRow[26];
    info[1] = matchRow[23];
    info[2] = matchRow[21];
    info[3] = matchRow[22];
    Logger.log(info);

    return info;
}
```

And here is my table.
[Asset Tag, Serial, Manufacturer, Model table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxfcy.png)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the problem. Is your  `searchColumn()` having issues? How is this function called to update your Docs table? please provide the complete code, with sample document (sheets and docs) and state the current issue.

Comment: @RonM, I am unsure how to make it auto populate a Doc table. I wrote this, but it is obviously incomplete I just don't know how to proceed

Comment: `
function fillDoc(row) {

  const doc = DocumentApp.openById('1eEGG_yyR4h6l1oCq5z0IOme2SNgBQmRGqJuiBAH1-b0');

  const body = doc.getBody();

  const table = body.getElement();

  Logger.log(table);

  //body.appendTableRow(row);
}`

edit: code is not formatting, unsure why, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

In your case this `matchRow = rows[index+1]` should this `matchRow = rows[index+2]`